# Linear regression with positive coefficients for SOME of the features in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, coefficients

I am trying to find a way to fit a linear regression. However I would like to force the coefficient of **some** drivers to be positive.

As far as I understood, [scipy.optimize.nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) can do non-negative least squares but for **all** drivers.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphical fitter that has a "brick wall" in the fitting function that forces one of the fitted parameters to be positive. Note that in this example, the fit is quite poor - if you remove the "brick wall" the example fit improves greatly. This example uses the default scipy curve_fit() initial parameter estimates of all 1.0, and does not use scipy's genetic algorithm to help find initial parameter estimates. When using this technique the initial parameter estimates must be outside the "brick wall" conditions so that the non-linear fitter can begin normally.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(x, a, b, offset): #exponential curve fitting function
    # force a to be positive by using "brick wall" that
    # returns a large value, and therefore a large error,
    # if parameter a is not positive
    if a <= 0.0:
        return 1.0E10
    return a * numpy.exp(-b*x) + offset


fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData)

print(fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Hi @JamesPhillips and happy new year!  As far as I understood in your exemple the target is predicted using only one driver.  But How do you apply it in the case of multivariate regression where some variable are constrainted to be positive and not other ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment regarding constrained multiple regression, here is a graphical 3D surface fitter that also has a "brick wall" to force one of the fitted parameters to be positive. The call to curve_fit can be made with either the constrained or unconstrained function versions for comparison.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, b, c):
    # extract the individual data arrays used in the equation
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]

    return a*x + b*y + c


def constrainedFunction(data, a, b, c):
    # use a "brick wall" to ensure parameter c is positive
    # return a large value and therefor large error
    if c <= 0.0:
        return 1.0E10
    else:
        return func(data, a, b, c) # call the unconstrained function


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([-10.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([-10.0, 11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 19.0])
    zData = numpy.array([-30.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(constrainedFunction, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scipy "curve_fit" curve fitting function you can specify the range of values for every coefficient. The keyworded argument passed to the "curve_fit" called "bounds" allow to specify range for every coefficient using a tuple. For example, if you pass quadratic function to "curve_fit" like a * x**2 + b * x and you want 0<"a"<2 and 1<"b"<4, you should pass to "curve_fit" keyworded argument bounds=([0,1], [2., 4.]).

```
def fit_func(xdata, a, b):
    return a * x**2 + b * x

params=curve_fit(fit_func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([0,1], [2, 4]))
```

"params" should give you a list of coefficient "a" and "b" in set range.

Link to documentation:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L549-L912